# How to cancel the last AT command ( Delphi - TComport )?

Tags: delphi, at-command, tcomport

I send this command "AT+CUSD=1,"*511#",15", the answer is:

'+CUSD: 1,"Points Noudjoum
1: Mes points
2: Convertir en Units
3: Convertir en cadeaux physiques
4: Points Bonus
5: Catalogue
6: Conso
Tapez 1-6",15'

Here I need to send again the integer 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 or 6 depending on the option i want but at this point I can't send another AT command "AT+CUSD=1,"*113#",15" for example, it shows an error because it is expected to send the number of the option.
How can I break or cancel it so I can send another AT command ?

Comment: New name for every question??  Try `at+cusd=1,2,15`   to choose `2: Convertir en Units`

Comment: @MBo His first question got two down votes. I think that is why he is doing this.

Comment: @MBo am not trying to know how to choose an option i want a command that cancels the first command so i can send other commands, Thank you anyway

Comment: @tom-brunberg nop its not mine

Comment: @nasreddine-galfout am not trying to hide who i am my friend i just want help with my problem, i couldn't ask more questions because of the down votes that's why i did that.

Comment: @TomBrunberg thnx man it works

Comment: Just of curiosity, and to learn more about the issue, which brand and model is your device?

Comment: @TomBrunberg i checked available commands using **AT+CUSD=?** and the answer was **+CUSD: (0-2)**, the device is Lonsai LS100, its a USB modem. Thanx again

Comment: Thanks for the info, mention it in future questions also.

Comment: @TomBrunberg no problem, yeah sure

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. There are  lots of people trying to abuse the system, I hope that with the votes gained from this post you can continue asking questions :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your device supports it, send a command

```
AT+CUSD=2
```

It is not clear whether all devices support it, but it is documented for some devices, (e.g. in `SIM7500_SIM7600 Series_AT Command Manual _V1.10`). Meaning is *cancel an ongoing USSD session*.

To find out whether the device supports this command, you can send

```
AT+CUSD=?
```

and the device will respond with the range accepted.